# SyntaxError when importing a module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've named a module as 'sort1.2' and now when I import this module it shows a syntax error. How can I import any module if it contains '.' character in its name?

```
>>> import sort1.2
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that instead of just taking two seconds to rename your module?

Comment: [*"Package and Module Names Modules should have short, **all-lowercase** names"*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: I just wanted to know instead...do u have any answer ?